# Initialization PostgreSQL with Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I'm trying to delete some entries based on the creation/expiry date in a PostrgreSQL DB only at the beginning, when the node server starts.
At present I put the line

**DELETE FROM ....db WHERE date <= CURRENT_DATE**

in the main route and it works, but that also mean that each time I refresh the page Node gets to execute that line, over and over again.

Is there a way to add a functionality for which the database knows and executes that line only once at the very beginning?
Should I create a different javascript function that fires at the beginning of the server.js file?

I'm using PostgreSQL, NodeJs and Express (no sequelize or similar).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a different javascript function that fires at the beginning of the server.js file?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a scripting language, which means that the code gets executed in the outer block (global scope). There is no main() function as in C/C++. So you should just put this line after the database initialization code in the outer program scope.